# Proportion with 3 variables - binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

So, if we're given something like this:
$$\binom{n}{k}:\binom{n+1}{k}:\binom{n+1}{k+1}=3:4:8$$
How do I rewrite this so I can manipulate it?

Edit: Is there a general procedure for n variables?

Comment: We have ${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} = \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n+1-k)!} = \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} {n+1\choose k}$ and you can derive similar expressions for the other fractions to get a simple equation system.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, what happens if we have only two binomial coefficients in a proportion and we want to get n and k? There seems to be lack of equations to solve such case.

Comment: Yes. One gets a relation between $n$ and $k$. For example the $3$:$4$ fraction is satisfied for all integers $n,k$ satisfying $4k = n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

> Note, that the equality of proportions
>   \begin{align*}
> a:b:c=x:y:z
> \end{align*}
>   is a compact notation for
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y},\qquad\frac{a}{c}=\frac{x}{z},\qquad\frac{b}{c}=\frac{y}{z}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   Each equality in (1) can be derived from the other two.

So, in order to check if we can solve
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}:\binom{n+1}{k}:\binom{n+1}{k+1}=3:4:8
\end{align*}
we take two proportions and calculate $n$ and $k$.

> We find by solving
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n+1}{k}}=\frac{3}{4}\qquad \frac{\binom{n+1}{k}}{\binom{n+1}{k+1}}=\frac{4}{8}
> \end{align*}
>
> the solutions $n=7,k=2$ and can finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{7}{2}:\binom{8}{2}:\binom{8}{3}=21:28:56=3:4:8
> \end{align*}